# React update nested object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React state object (myData) set as below (via React.useState)

```
{
    myPayloadInfo: myData.myPayloadInfo,
    isOriginDetails: true,
    originSuccessMsg: null
}
```

myData.myPayloadInfo looks as below

```
{
    "someVersion": 1,
    "someFlag": false
}
```

Now, I want to update "someFlag" to true in the overall "myData". How can I do that using the spread operator ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have used `useState`, I assume that you have used it as,

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState({
    myPayloadInfo: {
        someVersion: 1,
        someFlag: false
    },
    isOriginDetails: true,
    originSuccessMsg: null
});
```

To update the `someFlag`, You have to do

```
setMyData({
  ...myData,
  myPayloadInfo: {
     ...myData.myPayloadInfo,
     someFlag: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing the point, just spreading the full object, and then digging down to any required specifics should do the job:

```js
const data = {
  myPayloadInfo: {
    someVersion: 1,
    someFlag: false
  },
  isOriginDetails: true,
  originSuccessMsg: null
}

const newData = { 
  ...data,
  myPayloadInfo: {
    ...data.myPayloadInfo,
    someFlag: true,
  }
}

console.log(newData)
```